Interpretation of Distribution Function in Boltzmann Equation
The Wikipedia page on the Boltzmann equation says the following,

Since the probability of $N$ molecules, which all have $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ within $d^3\mathbf{r}d^3\mathbf{p}$, is in question, at the heart of the equation is a quantity $f$ which gives this probability per unit phase-space volume, or probability per unit length cubed per unit momentum cubed, at an instant of time t. This is a probability density function: $f(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{p}, t)$, defined so that, $d N = f (\mathbf{r} , \mathbf{p} , t )d^3\mathbf{r}d^3\mathbf{p}$ is the number of molecules which all have positions lying within a volume element $d^3\mathbf{r}$ about $\mathbf{r}$ and momenta lying within a momentum space element $d^3 \mathbf{p}$ about $\mathbf{p}$, at time $t$.

Now shouldn't $f (\mathbf{r} , \mathbf{p} , t )d^3\mathbf{r}d^3\mathbf{p}$ be regarded as the $probability$ of finding a particle in the given region of position-momentum space, rather than the absolute $number$ of particles within that region? Since the two are not synonymous, I'm not sure if the author is being rather cavalier with his probability theory or if there's something I'm missing.


Since the two are not synonymous

Despite they being not synonymous, they're closely related. If we have a system with $N$ total particles and $f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p, t)$ is the density of particles in the phase space at the time $t$,
$$
\Delta n  = f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t)\,\Delta \mathbf r\,\Delta \mathbf p
$$
is the number of particles between $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r+\Delta \mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf p+\Delta \mathbf p$ at time $t$, for small $\Delta \mathbf r$ and $\Delta \mathbf p$. The probability to find particles in this volume at time $t$ could be defined as
$$
p(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t) \equiv {\Delta n\over N} = \frac 1N f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t) \,\Delta \mathbf r \,\Delta \mathbf p.
$$
Now, the probability density in fact is defined as $\rho(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t) = \frac 1N f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t)$. In the text that you mentioned, the author is referring to $f$ as if it was $\rho$, but they differ by the factor $\frac 1N$, or, more rigorously, the only difference is the normalization factor
$$
\int_V f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t)\,d\mathbf r \,d\mathbf p = N
$$
and
$$
\int_V \rho(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t)\,d\mathbf r \,d\mathbf p = 1.
$$

The use of unormalized distributions is not uncommon in physics. In fact, they present some advantages, principally when we are dealing with differential equations for $f(\mathbf r,\mathbf p,t)$. In this context, the normalization condition is dealt as an additional constraint. Some texts do not care to distinguish between density function and probability density function because of that, and this article is just an example of what you could find in some books also.
